# Anyone understand what these instructions are asking, and know how to write this in assembly?

Tags: assembly, intel, cpu-architecture, modular-arithmetic

> **Problem**- Using the Intel86 simulator, given three one-byte numbers X, Y and Z
>   `(1<X,Y,Z<100)`,
>    write the code that computes the modular exponentiation
>   X^y mod Z (Example, X=4, Y=3, Z=5 result = 4). X, Y and Z ARE FOUND in
>   memory positions 107H, 108H and 109H of your program, so make sure you
>   do not use those bytes for instructions. The result of the calculation
>   should must be stored in DL.The algorithm code to be used to compute
>   the modular exponentiation X^y mod Z is: d,1. Assume that Y is
>   represented by bits Yk,Yk-1,Yk-2,...Y0 For j <-- k down to zero
>       d <-- (d*d) % Z
>       IF Y1 == 1 then d <-- (d*X) % Z result is in d.

Comment: If you don't understand your assignment you should talk to your tutor about it. [So] is not a place to get your homework done free of charge.

Comment: Consider visiting http://stackoverflow.com/tour to learn how SO works.

Comment: Simply asking if someone can translate this problem to me better than my "tutor" can.

Comment: Could you please describe what "Intel86 simulator" is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the algorithm is poorly worded, and also backwards, assuming the goal is to repeatedly square X mod Z to speed up the process.

```
    R = 1;
    goto loop1;
loop0: 
    if(Y & 1) /* if least signficant bit of Y is set */
        R = (R * X) % Z;
    X = (X * X) % Z
    Y = (Y >> 1) /* logical (unsigned) shift right) */
loop1:
    if(Y != 0)
        goto loop0;
    DL = R;
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is a typo "IF Y1 ..." should be "IF Yj ...". Also the algorithm is incomplete, there should be a shift anywhere. Here is an example for the algorithm in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
    unsigned char X = 4, Y = 3, Z = 5;

    printf("(%d ^ %d) %% %d = ",X,Y,Z);

    unsigned int d = 1;
    for (int j=7; j>=0; --j)
    {
        d = (d*d) % Z;
        if (Y & 0x80)           // leftest bit (Yj) set?
        {
            d = (d * X) % Z;
        }
        Y <<= 1;
    }

    printf("%d\n", d);

    return 0;
}
```

If I only knew what "Intel86 simulator" is ... ;-)